# Javascript balloon-looking dialog

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML table. When the user clicks on some cell - I am displaying a JavaScript dialog (currently using jQuery), where user enters some information related to this cell.

So I am looking for framework, which would visually connect the dialog to the cell being edited.

Pretty much like balloon tooltip.

Anybody saw this? probably JQuery plugin?

Thanks

**UPDATE:** I am currently using qTip - it totally does what I wanted

Comment: If you want a tooltip, couldn't you just use a `title` attribute?

Comment: Eric, i don't want a tooltip - i want a dialog, which WILL LOOK like tooltip.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. Didn't see the "dialog ... *where user enters some information*" bit

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I used [overLIB](http://www.bosrup.com/web/overlib/) for this. You can style it to look like a standard tooltip - maybe this is what you are searching for.

Comment: Right, this is tooltip facility. I guess i can tweak it, but i was looking for ready-to-use solution.
Thanks anyway.